# React-Select: "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" when I type in the Select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am implementing React-Select Async. According to their documentation, my code is correct. Yet, onInputChange throws the error "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"each as soon as I type something. How to fix this?

```js
const options=[
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
]
export default function App() {
const [query, setQuery] = useState('')
  const handleInputChange = (str) => {
    const inputValue = str.replace(/\W/g, '');
    setQuery(inputValue);
    return inputValue;
  };
  return (
    <>
     <AsyncSelect
          cacheOptions
          //loadOptions={loadOptions}
          defaultOptions={options}
          onInputChange={(e)=> handleInputChange(e.target.value)}
        />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when `onInputChange` event is fired, `handleInputChange` function is passed the input value by `react-select`. So yo don't need to pass the value manually.

So change

```
onInputChange={(e)=> handleInputChange(e.target.value)}
```

to

```
onInputChange={handleInputChange}
```

Also you need to set `isAsync` prop to true

[image: Edit happy-easley-w08wf]

Comment: It's a typo in my question, but there's no such error in my code. The issue persists. If I write onChange of their onInputChange, I don't have error anymore, but the filter doesn't work.

Comment: Sure: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-margulis-xlnzj?file=/src/App.js & the official exemple for async select: https://react-select.com/home#async

Answer (score 0):

`onInputChange={(e)=> handleInputChange(ee.target.value)}` . You put 'ee.target...' instead of 'e.target...'

Comment: It's a typo in my question, but there's no such error in my code. The issue persists.